# Centrar texto en un botón

Tags: html, css

Tengo este pequeño dilema en el cual no se me centra el texto en un botón en `HTML`.

**Imagen Descriptiva:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Botón:**

```
<nav class="bot">
        <center>
            <input type="button" name="Chequera" value="Cuotas" onclick="location.href='javascript:cuotas()'" />
            <input type="button" name="Certificados" value="Certificados" onclick="location.href='javascript:certificaciones()'" />
        </center>
        <center>
            <input type="button" name="Solicitudes" value="Solicitudes" onclick="location.href='javascript:solicitudes()'" />
            <input type="button" name="Titulos" value="Títulos" onclick="location.href='javascript:titulos()'" />
        </center>
    </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bot {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

¿Cómo lo puedo centrar? Es el que dice  **Certificaciones**

Comment: Como nada de código de C# ni de MVC existe en la pregunta, eliminé las etiquetas dejando solamente las que tienen que ver con la pregunta en sí (basado en el código mostrado).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones:

```
.bot {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

input[type=button], input[type=submit] {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 32px; //Original
    padding: 16px 24px; //nuevo, opción A
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 120px; // Original
    width: 140px; // nuevo, opción B
    text-align:center;
}
```

Dato importante: a tener en cuenta la longitud de las palabras para evitar que el padding que se les da, limiten las letras.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha servido de maravilla

Comment: ¡Excelente! Sigue adelante :D una recomendación bro: se un gran amigo de las developer tools, a.k.a: F12, en el mundo del desarrollo web, es un gran aliado. Éxitos :D

Answer (score 1):

Es por el padding, dejale solo asi:

```
padding: 16px;
```